# C# ListView in List mode adjust Item width

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, width

How to set Item's length in a `ListView` that is displayed as `List`?

The data set is a list of strings.  I don't need columns.  I need to be able to change the strings font so I guess `ListView` is what I need to use.

I've placed a `ListView` control in my application using VS designer but after inserting an item using `Items.Add()` the added item is not displayed fully, ex: `abc...`, when there is enough width to the control to allow for entire item text to be displayed.

How do I set item width so that it's not cut off with periods?

Here is what it looks like:
http://i44.tinypic.com/dyvl1t.jpg

Comment: I'd assume you mean datasource is a list of strings. If so, is there anything different about them? If you have some code, paste it up and I'll try it out myself, becasue my listview is functioning fine when attached to a list of strings.

Comment: What I'm doing is creating a string[] and copying it into ListView.Items property via ListView.Items.AddRange(string[]) and then just displaying whatever was added.  My control is right aligned and there are only about 10 chars shown when 30 would easily fit in a line.

Comment: Entry ends up looking like "_________text..."  _ is space

Comment: Where are these strings coming from? I've seen strange cases where they are read from somewhere and have whitespace attached to the front causing this problem. (I'm going to transition home from work, so my next response may be slightly delayed.)

Comment: listView_members.Items.Add("[" + sup.UserState + "] " + user);  That rules out the space beginning.

Comment: Still hard to say. You could step through the process via break points and watch the variables get added to make sure they are trimmed of all white space. If that holds true, then I'd know for sure that the problem would reside with the control and not the data.

Comment: This is what's in the ListView.Items collection: {Text = "[Chatting] userName"}, taken from debug window, so no leading spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Boy I feel stupid.

It appears that I had two columns defined.  Once I removed all the column definitions all is as should be.

Answer (score 2):

*Set ListView property named **View** to **List***.
There are various view to see data of listview. You can change it by setting various View property.

*In your case you have to set it to **List**.*

Comment: That is already done, by stating "displayed as List", I meant what you are suggesting here :)

Comment: Have you set **View property to List**?

Comment: Yes, I have. [comment must be min 15 chars]